# Hiding columns containing errors macro

Tags: excel, vba, hide

new to VBA and building a macro such that when cells contain an error it when hide the column. I tried this after looking around a bit and it doesn't work for me at all - "error 13"?

```
`Sub Hide_error()
'hides errors in the price tab

Sheets("blah").Select

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("B1:JQ262")
If c.Value = "#Value!" Then
c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End If
Next c

End Sub`
```

Really struggling to find a way of getting a solution to this.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Text `#Value!` is  not the *value* of the cell, it is just the way Excel tells you that there is something wrong - maybe an invalid formula.

To check this in VBA, use the function `isError`:

```
if isError(c.Value) then
```

An *error* is handled as special type in VBA, and if you compare an error with a string (or any other data type), you get an error 13 ("Type mismatch").

Comment: Thanks for that! Worked perfectly!